# mariadb automate replication resync using windows task scheduler

Tags: mariadb

1. Built Master - to multi-slave for different locations(servers)replication setup.
2. Need batch file script to be run under windows task scheduler to automate replication status.

if Replication breaks and last error found, hit   some  commands to stable replication status. Also generate logs for every server.

Comment: And which question do you have?

Comment: Let's see some examples of "breaks".

Comment: i need batch script to run under windows task scheduler every 2 minutes , check slave status , if slave status OK then exit otherwise do skip error by counter 1  until slave is stable

Comment: do you understand why the replication errors are happening? Can you prevent them?

Comment: I know and understand why the replication errors are happening. I have already prevented many.